# Trying to mimic windows search with PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

So I'm trying to replicate the behavior of windows 10 native search bar, e.g:

- user presses some key combo -> search bar appears, already having input focus
- user clicks away\focus is lost -> search bar disappears

Ive got most of it to work the way I want it to, my entire app is a single window which inherits from `QMainWindow` and I use `self.hide()` on it once I detect focus is lost..

Ive bound some key combo to the method below with the `keyboard` library:

```
def bringToTop(self) -> None:
    print('got focus')
    self.show()
    self.raise_()
    self.setWindowState(self.windowState() & ~Qt.WindowMinimized | Qt.WindowActive)
    self.activateWindow()
    self.lineEdit.setFocus()
```

I just want the window to come up and set input focus on the `lineEdit`, but instead it just flashes in orange in the taskbar.

Ive tried many combinations of the lines in `bringToTop`, nothing worked.

Simplified version of my code:

```
import sys
import keyboard
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFocusEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QApplication


class SearchWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setEnabled(True)
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.setFixedSize(300, 50)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint))

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(30, 10, 230, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setFocusPolicy(Qt.ClickFocus)

        keyboard.add_hotkey('win+z', self.bringToTop)
        self.bringToTop()

    def focusOutEvent(self, a0: QFocusEvent) -> None:
        self.hide()

    def bringToTop(self) -> None:
        print('got focus')
        self.show()
        self.raise_()
        self.setWindowState(self.windowState() & ~Qt.WindowMinimized | Qt.WindowActive)
        self.activateWindow()
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SearchWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Windows will not allow this, it is call "focus stealing" https://duckduckgo.com/?q=focus+stealing&t=ffab&ia=web. You can try by creating a new instance of the application every time you capture the combination of keys.

Comment: @Isma If windows really doesn't allow this, do you know by chance how software like ShareX or other screen captures work? In ShareX once I press a certain key combo, my entire screen essentially becomes a screenshot and I can then select an area to save.. This seems to me like something that completely violates what you just said, since the program essentially becomes on top and is now getting all input from the user.

Comment: You can focus the first time you create an application thread, so you could try to create a new QApplication on a new thread when win+z is pressed. I can make an example if you want.

Comment: @Isma please do, sounds like it could solve the problem

Comment: did you find how to do it ? If so can you share your solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

[`QWidget.activateWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow) documentation reports that:

> On Windows, if you are calling this when the application is not
>   currently the active one then it will not make it the active window.
>   It will change the color of the taskbar entry to indicate that the
>   window has changed in some way. This is because Microsoft does not
>   allow an application to interrupt what the user is currently doing in
>   another application.

There's also [`QWindow.requestActivate()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#requestActivate), even if I'm afraid that it'll have the same result.

Unfortunately I cannot test it as I'm on Linux right now, but [`QWindowsWindowFunctions.setWindowActivationBehavior()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindowswindowfunctions.html#setWindowActivationBehavior) might be promising.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither PyQt nor PySide implements the `QWindowsWindowFunctions` class. The `requestActivate` method requires the correct activation-behaviour flag to be set, so that won't work either.